# Same script, different object, different shuffle result

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a  script to shuffle an object behaviour. Lets say behaviour 1-sit, 2-jump, 3-walk, 4-run. Then there's a script attached to the object to shuffle the object's behaviour. For example the shuffled behaviour is 3-1-2-4. When I duplicate the object, all duplicated object has the same shuffle result so all object behaviour is the same. What i want is different object has different shuffle result. All i can think is to make a different script for each object, but that's not efficient.

[edit] here's the script attached to the object

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StudentScript : MonoBehaviour {

private System.Random _random = new System.Random();
private Animator animator;
float sec;
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int m;
public GameManage gm;
public Animator pengawasAnim;
public Animator signAnim;

void Start () {
    animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    sec = 0f;
    m = 0;
    Shuffle(array);
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Debug.Log(value);
    }
}

void Update () {
    sec+=Time.deltaTime;
    if (sec >= 3f && m<5 && animator.GetInteger ("Behav") == 0) { 
        StudentBehaviour(array[m]);
    }
    //Debug.Log ("sec "+sec);
    if (animator.GetInteger ("Behav") != 0) {
        if (sec >= 5)
            animator.SetTrigger ("ToDont");
        if (sec >= 10)
            animator.SetTrigger ("ToEffect");
    }
}

public void StudentBehaviour(int n){
    animator.SetInteger ("Behav", n);
    sec = 0f;
    Debug.Log ("jadi "+n);
}

public void ResetStudentBehaviour(){
    if (animator.GetInteger ("Behav") != 0) {
        pengawasAnim.SetTrigger("Approach");
        if (sec >= 0f && sec <=5f) {
            signAnim.SetTrigger ("ToYellow");
            animator.SetTrigger ("Told1");
            gm.AddScore (5);
        }else if (sec >= 5f && sec <=10f) {
            signAnim.SetTrigger ("ToOrange");
            animator.SetTrigger ("Told2");
            animator.ResetTrigger ("ToDont");
            gm.AddScore (3);
        }else if (sec >= 10f) {
            signAnim.SetTrigger ("ToRed");
            animator.SetTrigger ("Told3");
            animator.ResetTrigger ("ToEffect");
            gm.AddScore (1);
        }
        animator.SetInteger ("Behav", 0);
        sec = 0f;
        Debug.Log ("reset");
        if (m < 5) {
            m++;
        } 
        Debug.Log ("m = " + m);
        Debug.Log ("sec "+sec);
    }else
        Debug.Log ("student done <3");
}

void Shuffle(int[] array){
    int p = array.Length;
    for (int n = p-1; n > 0 ; n--)
    {
        int r = _random.Next(0, n);
        int t = array[r];
        array[r] = array[n];
        array[n] = t;
    }
}
```

What i want is to duplicate the student (the one with goggles) so the behaviour each student is shuffled differently

[image]

Comment: but how can we help you without your code? how can one see how you duplicate your object?

Comment: @Programmer edited. sorry :)

Comment: No problem. Where is the code you use to duplicate the student? That's very important to pin-point the problem.

Comment: but i duplicate the student manually

Comment: From the Editor? not from Code? If this is true, then your shuffle code is broken

Comment: Looked at it more. It wasn't that. Look at my answer for the solution.

Comment: why oh why are you using System.Random?  Just use the ordinary Random.Range which Unity gives you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line `private System.Random _random = new System.Random();`.

Simply add the `static` keyword in front that line.

```
static private System.Random _random = new System.Random();
```

This solves the problem. Although **sometimes**, the random numbers from different Object instances are the-same but that is rare. To **reduce** the probability of different Object getting the-same random number, dedicate a class and GameObject for the `Shuffle(int[] array)` function then call the function from many instances of the `StudentScript` class.

So create a class called `RandomGen` and create a GameObject and name it **RANDOMOBJ**. Attach the `RandomGen` script to the **RANDOMOBJ** GameObject.

Don't duplicate it(**RANDOMOBJ**). There should be one of them.

Your `RandomGen` script:

```
public class RandomGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    static private System.Random _random = new System.Random();


    public void Shuffle(int[] array)
    {
        int p = array.Length;
        for (int n = p - 1; n > 0; n--)
        {
            int r = _random.Next(0, n);
            int t = array[r];
            array[r] = array[n];
            array[n] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `StudentScript` script.

```
public class StudentScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    RandomGen randomGen;

    private Animator animator;
    float sec;
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int m;
    public GameManage gm;
    public Animator pengawasAnim;
    public Animator signAnim;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sec = 0f;
        m = 0;
        randomGen = GameObject.Find("RANDOMOBJ").GetComponent<RandomGen>();

        randomGen.Shuffle(array);
        foreach (int value in array)
        {
            Debug.Log(value);
        }
    }

//.... Put your other functions below, except the Shuffle function
}
```

Comment: why not just use UnityEngine.Random? just out of curiosity.

Comment: @yes **1**. I used that because that's what she used. I don't know if she is required to use that. **2.** `UnityEngine.Random` and `System.Random` are the-same thing. **3.** `using System.Random` is not the reason the code is not working.

Comment: At least you cant unintentionally seed UnityEngine.Random with the same value if you create multiple instances within a short timeframe. (since you cant instantiate it) And isnt that what you supsect to happen in the above code?

Comment: i was just wondering since from reading your answers i can tell you  know a whole lot more about unity and probably even c# then i do.

Comment: @yes I used it because the OP did. Also `UnityEngine.Random` < `System.Random` in terms of flexibility. `UnityEngine.Random`  is  missing many functions such as  the `Next` function and that is required to make OP's code work. Bear in mind that the OP is using `Random.Next` instead of `Random.Range`. These are two different different things.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int r =  Random.value*n;
```

or:

```
int r = Random.Range(0,n);
```

instead of:

```
int r = _random.Next(0, n);
```

in your Shuffle() method

Comment: She used `int r = _random.Next(0, n);` because she wants all the values in the arrays to be different. I also think that the shuffle function is the problem but I don't think this solves the problem.

Comment: @Programer You are right.

you're right. My mistake was believing that Random.next gives a predefined sequence of random numbers.

I have done some testing in. And the only difference is that Random.Range() returns  floats

Comment: Random.Range has an overload for integer, where it returns integer, aswell.

Answer (score -1):

Add this method to your GameObject and call it in the Start()

```
int[] shuffleArray(int[] OriginalArray)
{
    int[] tempCopy = (int[])OriginalArray.Clone();
    int[] tempCopy2 = (int[])OriginalArray.Clone();
    int[] shuffledArray = new int[OriginalArray.Length];

    for (int n = 0; n < shuffledArray.Length; n++)
    {
        //Asign a random OriginalArray's data to the n data of shuffledArray
        int randomValue = _random.Next(0, tempCopy.Length);
        print("n="+n+" randomValue="+randomValue+ " tempCopy.lenght="+ tempCopy.Length);
        shuffledArray[n] = tempCopy[randomValue];

        //Erase the data extracted and reduce the copy of OriginalArray in one
        if (tempCopy2.Length != 0)
        {
            tempCopy2 = new string[tempCopy2.Length - 1];
            for (int m = 0; m < randomValue; m++) tempCopy2[m] = tempCopy[m];
            for (int m = randomValue; m < tempCopy.Length-1; m++) tempCopy2[m] = tempCopy[m + 1];
        }
        tempCopy = tempCopy2;
    }

    return shuffledArray;
}
```

This code returns a shuffled copy of the Array you give.

Comment: Allocating memory with `tempCopy`,`tempCopy2` and `shuffledArray` 3 times in a simple function. Returning allocated memory in a function is not good too. This is bad. Each time you call `shuffleArray`, unnecessary memory allocation will happen.  That's why the original function takes, array as a parameter so that the shuffled result can be returned to that parameter without allocating memory.

Comment: thnks for read my answer @Programmer.


But your solution doesn't work because the function random.Next(0, n); can return the same value twice.

I also thought that random.Next() returns a predefined random secuence but your code can overwrite the same value all times in the loop here:

----'array[r] = array[n]; ---

because r can get the same value all times

Comment: ofc Random can return the same value twice, even trice, that can happen. but for shuffling the array the way OP did its unimportant, as the random value is only used for the index of the element to switch.

Comment: **But your solution doesn't work because the function random.Next(0, 10); can return the same value twice.**. I think that you don't the OP's question. The `Shuffle` function in the OP's question works 100%.... The `Shuffle` function is NOT the problem. It shuffles numbers in array n and it returns the result to the array that is passed in. Because of this, the function does not need to allocate memory 3 times and it will not return a new array which is faster and memory friendly.

Comment: The problem the OP is having is that when there are multiple instances of the script, the shuffle still works but the two instances will have the-same shuffle numbers. `instance1 shuffledNumbers == instance2 shuffledNumbers`. OP wants the numbers to be different on each instance. Making the Random class static is recommended and that **ALMOST** solved the problem. It works most of the time. To really solve the problem, make sure there is one instance of `System.Random` running then you can access it from other classes. This **FULLY** solved the problem and no more duplicates.

Comment: I will be good if you actually run somebody's code before claiming it doesn't work. As for your code, I don't know if it works or not but even if does, it is very inefficient(GC) and  and buggy(returning new array) compared to OP's code.

Comment: ok.. ok... In future I will try to run the code bfore open my f**** mouth